# Issue with creating a query in mongodb with NumberLong

Tags: java, mongodb, criteria-api, mongotemplate

I've got a class in my Java application with field

```
Instant created;
```

This one is stored in mongo as

```
"created" : NumberLong("1467359610266") (f.e.)
```

I want to create a query to get all the documents, that was created beetween 2 dates:

```
    public List<MarketingEmail> find(Long startDate, Long endDate) {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("created").gte(startDate).lte(endDate));
    ...
}
```

I pass the timestamp variables startDate and endDate (f.e. endDate = 1467981757).
So the issues is that NumberLong in MongoDB has 13 digits, when my timestamp has ony 10; so my query doesn't work at all

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongo timestamp uses milliseconds.

To query it multiply your value by 1000 (or simple add `000` at the end)